# Django Project- CSS

Tags: django

I have a base.html file in my Django project in a the templates directory that is in the main project folder. I want my base.html to locate my file, so where should I be putting it in the project? I'm new to Django.

Comment: Read the [static files tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial06/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first create a static directory inside your app. Then create a css directory inside the static directory. Place your `.css` file inside this css directory. That will be the directory structure. You will need to configure the `settings.py` file to configure your static files and place a `{% load static %}` at the top of each html template. You can then link to this file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/example.css' %}"/>
```

For more info on managing static files see here:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

Comment: My base.html is not in the app folder but in the in the templates folder that comes under the main project. Will that work if I keep the static directory inside the app?